# how does a host learn about other hosts IP addresses connected on the same subnet?

Tags: ipv4, ip-address, arp, ip-link-local

My question is similar to one posted [here][1]

But answers are not understandable to me. **How can a host (say my laptop) learn about IP addresses of other devices (say my phone) on the same subnet**. Only then my laptop can make ARP table because it can query for MAC address only if it has the ip address.
[1]: [How does a host know the ip addresses of other hosts on the same LAN?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64268/how-does-a-host-know-the-ip-addresses-of-other-hosts-on-the-same-lan)

Comment: Your question is really a duplicate of the one to which you refer. Unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers, applications, and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditionally, *DNS* is used to refer to known hosts - usually to servers as simple peers are of little interest.

There's also a large variety of *discovery protocols* that use multicast or broadcast to learn of neighboring nodes/services (LLDP, CDP, UPnP, Bonjour, ...), but there's no general standard.

Of course, you can also run an ARP sweep over your subnet to locate existing nodes/valid IP addresses.

Comment: So my windows-10 discovering a printer on the network is basically running one such proprietary Microsoft ARP sweep?

Comment: Many printer drivers include a proprietary protocol for printer discovery (something like Bonjour can also be used). However, these devices and protocols are off-topic here, see the [help].